# Spring: Value from a properties file is not autowired

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring 4. My configuration is:

***web.xml***

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:contexts/root/spring-root-context.xml
        classpath:contexts/security/security-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

***spring-root-context.xml***

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:credentials.properties" />
```

***security-context.xml***

```
<beans:bean id="myCustomFilter" class="filters.MyCustomFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>
```

***credentials.properties***

ClientSecret=qwerty

***MyCustomFilter.java***

```
public class MyCustomFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    @Value("${ClientSecret}")
    private String clientSecret;

}
```

The properties file is loaded

```
INFO RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1 support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer:172 - Loading properties file from class path resource [credentials.properties]
```

The value of clientSecret is not injected.

Comment: did you add `<context:annotation-config>` tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't have `<context:annotation-config>` in your `spring-root-context.xml`.

From other side, if you configure `MyCustomFilter` as a `<bean>` just use it's property:

```
<beans:bean id="myCustomFilter" class="filters.MyCustomFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="clientSecret" value="${ClientSecret}" />
</beans:bean>
```

If you have `setter` for that, of course.

Comment: Yeah, I totally missed that. Thanks.